# autolink stealing the ontouch event and thus feedback on touching a listview row not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, autolink

I have a `listview`. And a row layout containing few layouts in it.
Inside the row layout I have a `TextView` on which I want to enable autolink
When I am enabling the autolink, the link is working fine but the feedback which we get when we click a list row is not working anymore.

When within the row layout, I click anywhere outside the `Textview`, it gives the feedback, but when I am clicking on the `TextView` it is not giving the feedback.

So I am guessing that the autolink for the textview is stealing the `ontouchevent`, and thus it is not reaching to the list view feedback functionality.

This is the xml code for the list row view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:focusable="false"
android:background="@color/Green">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/delivery_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@color/Blue"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Delivery date"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="@color/White"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        cardview:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        cardview:cardElevation="5dp"
        cardview:cardBackgroundColor="@color/White"
        cardview:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="M"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:background="@color/Blue"
    />

    <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/Share"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/message_text"
      android:focusable="true"
      android:layout_margin="5dp"
      android:background="@drawable/share3"
    android:adjustViewBounds="True" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/time"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Share"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Share"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_margin="5dp"
     android:text="Timexxxxx"
     android:layout_gravity="right"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
     android:textColor="@color/Time" />

 <ImageView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_above="@+id/time"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:paddingBottom="2dp"
     android:paddingLeft="5dp"
     android:paddingRight="5dp"
     android:paddingTop="2dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright" />

 </RelativeLayout>
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

CAn anyone please help here? Also if anyone can explain any rules related to how the events are passed from children to parent, and relevance of properties like `android:focusable` and `android:descendantFocusability` ?

Thanks a ton in advance!